# Webkit scroll position lost

Tags: webkit, position, scrolltop

On Webkit re-rendering any of an outer containers (div in my case) child elements or changing on of these childs display attribute from/to display:none/block/inline/inline-block whatsoever, courses the container element to scroll back to top. This way elements located at the lower end of the scrolling area are never be reached by the user since this area keeps scrolling back to top as soon as one of previously mentioned things occure.

On Firefox the scroll position is maintained as required.

[Example](http://app.webpremiere.de/director_app) (expand left-hand list to force scrollbar to appear or choose an album on the left so that the main display area has enough content to bring up scrollbars, scroll to the bottom and hover over the images)

Is there any workaround/fix I could implement to keep the user experience also for webkit browsers?

Thanks

Comment: your example is broken, please create a **simplified** demo using **[dabblet](http://dabblet.com/)** or **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)**. i encountered the same issue (presumably) while using GXT's tree grid with text selection enabled.

Comment: BTW - my problem is solved by upgrading GXT (2.2.4 -> 2.2.5).